# Verifying bitcoin core testnet transactions on blockcypher

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet, bitcore

After successfully creating wallet in bitcoincore UI and transferring testnet coins from one wallet to another wallet, i decdied to verify my transactions on live blockcyper but using the transaction id i can view my transactions there but the numbers does not match like bitcoin value does not match or the size of the transaction does not match.... wondering why is that.

This is how it looks like in Bitcoin Core UI

[image]

Now same transaction in blockcypher show different bitcoin amount and size there

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be a useful reference [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84289/information-to-recipient-of-the-transaction)

As far as I know, the explorers don't really have a way to decode the receiver and the recipient, the only point of the transaction that contains the information on senders and recipients are the scripts, look at this [reference](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script).

But I can't guarantee you that the blockchain explorers use those to understand from whom and where bitcoins start and arrive.

I hope I have been helpful and excuse my terrible English but I am learning